# jquery : update css on one table column based on attribute of another column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my HTML table

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<table>
<thead>
<th>Header1</th>
<th>Header2</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" id=0 /></td>
<td>TEXT1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" id=1 checked/></td>
<td>TEXT2</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

[please click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAuF8.png)

My objective is to scan all the rows in the table (after the page has been loaded ) and update the css of the second column's text via jquery (shown in the link)

For example the table above should be rendered as above (with the element TEXT2 striked through)

I believe we can set the css of an element using jquery's css method something like below

```
.css("text-decoration", "line-through")
```

but I am lost as to how to build a jquery snippet that can scan all the rows in the table and perform the css.

Is this really possible in jquery ?

Any help is appreciated !!!

Comment: To clarify, is `checked` the *attribute* referred to in the title of this question?

Comment: Yes. If the first column (which contains a input checkbox) has “checked” attribute present, then I need to apply the strike through css on the second column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. Initializing the script**

To run script *after* page-load, consider using the `.on()` method with the `load` event.

Ref: [.on() | jQuery API Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

**2. Iterating through specified elements:**

To loop through required elements, consider using the `.each()` method with the specified css selectors `td > input`, as to target directly nested `input` elements of `td` elements (and thereby circumventing the targeting of all `input` elements that happen to be nested in any particular `td` element, and negating the need to chain another `.find()` method to specify the required nested elements).

Ref: [.each() | jQuery API Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

**3.Checking the required condition:**

To verify if the element in question has the attribute `checked`, consider using a *conditional statement*, like `if()`, to check if the condition evaluates to `true`.
*if* it does, add the required *inline style* using the `.css()` method within the conditional statement block.

Ref: [.css() | jQuery API Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/css/)

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```js
$(window).on('load', function(){
  
  $('td > input').each(function(){
    if($(this).attr('checked')) {
      $(this).parent().next().css('text-decoration', 'line-through');
    }
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Header1</th>
    <th>Header2</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" id="text0" /></td>
      <td>TEXT1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" id="text1" checked/></td>
      <td>TEXT2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

*Note:*

1. `id` selectors are invalid if the value begins with an integer
   (number/unit value), e.g: `id="0"`, the value must begin with a
   string, e.g: `id="text0"`
2. Wrap attribute values in apostrophes, e.g: `id="text0"`

Answer (score 0):

i did this in Jquery:

striking out text on second column which has checked checkbox.

but also included to to strike out text on second column is user user clicks check box

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('input:checkbox').on('change', function () {
        var inpt = $(this).parent().next('td');
        if (this.checked) {
           
            $(inpt).css('textDecoration', 'line-through');
        } else {
            $(inpt).css('textDecoration', 'none');
        }
    });
  var i=   $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').parent().next('td');
  if ($('input[type=checkbox]:checked')) {
           
            $(i).css('textDecoration', 'line-through');
            }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
<table>
<thead>
<th>Header1</th>
<th>Header2</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" id=0 /></td>
<td>TEXT1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" id=1 checked/></td>
<td>TEXT2</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```